# Left join with count return one result

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have two tables.

```
|Table One: Adversitements-----------------------|
| ID |                                  ADVTITLE |
|----|-------------------------------------------|
|  1 |                   IT Staff will be taken. |
|  2 |  Human resources personnel will be taken. |
|  3 |               CNC Operator will be taken. |

|Table Two: Applications-----|
| ID | ADVID | APPLICANTNAME |
|----|-------|---------------|
|  1 |     1 |      John Doe |
|  2 |     1 |    John Doe 2 |
|  3 |     1 |      Jane Doe |
|  4 |     2 |      John Doe |
|  5 |     2 |      Jane Doe |
|  6 |     3 |      John Doe |
```

**I Want result:**

```
|                ADVTITLE                   | APPLICANTCOUNT |
|-------------------------------------------|----------------|
| IT Staff will be taken.                   |              3 |
| Human resources personnel will be taken.  |              2 |
| CNC Operator will be taken.               |              1 |
```

But returning a single result;
**OUTPUT:**

```
|                ADVTITLE | APPLICANTCOUNT |
|-------------------------|----------------|
| IT Staff will be taken. |              6 |
```

**MySQL Query**;

```
SELECT adv.advtitle, COUNT(applications.id) as applicantCount 
FROM advertisements as adv 
LEFT JOIN applications 
ON adv.id = applications.advid
```

All listings can be related to how the number of applicants?

SQL Fiddle Link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8644c/1/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT adv.advtitle, COUNT(applications.id) as applicantCount
FROM advertisements as adv
LEFT JOIN applications ON adv.id = applications.advid 
GROUP BY adv.advtitle
ORDER BY applicantCount desc
```

Result:

```
ADVTITLE                                   APPLICANTCOUNT
---------------------------------------------------------
IT Staff will be taken.                     3
Human resources personnel will be taken..   2
CNC Operator will be taken.                 1
```

[**Fiddle Example**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8644c/20)

Answer (score 0):

You need `GROUP BY` clause

```
SELECT adv.advtitle, COUNT(applications.id) as applicantCount 
FROM advertisements as adv 
LEFT JOIN applications 
ON adv.id = applications.advid 
GROUP BY applications.advid
```

<kbd>[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8644c/10)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

i already test it on my own try to paste it in your sqlfiddle :)

```
SELECT A.advtitle,COUNT(B.advid) AS ApplicantCount FROM advertisements A
LEFT JOIN applications B ON B.advid = A.id
GROUP BY A.id
```